# Get the frequency of a three phase voltage without a PLL?

Tags: pll, zero-crossing

I would like to get the phase and therefore the frequency of a three phase voltage, and with using a simple transformation (Clarke). so I get a stationary alpha - beta voltages. Then I will use an atan function to get the phase, but the problem is how can I see if I am treating a sine or a cosine voltage. I mean the problem of initial phase must be obtained. Is there any idea to get this synchronisation without the use of zero crossing detection.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I have found the solution. By using the Clarke Transformation we get to values (one on the d and the other on the q axis), after that I use the atan2 function which is the four quadrant inverse tangent.

Answer (score 0):

What is it exactly that you are trying to do? Do you mean three phase voltage as in the power grid? If you need to get the frequency of a three phase voltage of the power grid, there are basically two options.

First is to do what you call zero crossing detection: you calculate the number of zero crossings per time unit. That is an easy way to get the frequency, but it takes a relatively long time. For example 1 second to get an accuracy of one hertz.

The second option is to get a moderately long vector of samples of the voltage. Something like 5..10 waves or more. Then Hann-filter the vector and run a correlator to it. You know, multiply it with 0.01 Hz sine and cosine signals and calculate the power; then repeat for 0.02 Hz, then 0.03 Hz and so forth. Of course you probably already have a fairly good estimate of the signal's frequency; if you know it's about 60 Hz, then you can start the correlator at 59.00 Hz and step from there.

As a side note: someone might suggest you to do a fast Fourier transform (FFT), but what is FFT anyway? It's a series of correlator banks. If you already roughly know the frequency, there's no need to calculate the whole frequency spectrum from zero to Fs/2. Just correlate the range of frequencies that you need based on the rough estimate.

The power grid is noisy, so any immediate samples you get are too noisy to detect any phase information with any accuracy. You need longer sample periods and/or filtering.

Phase has no relevance to your titled question. But you can calculate different kinds of phase information from the voltage samples; you pick one of the voltages as the phase reference and compare others to it. And if it's energy meters you're involved with, doing the same with currents also opens up the possibilities of calculating active, reactive and apparent powers and energies.

Comment: effectively, I would like to get the frequency of a three phase voltage in a grid. I calculate the V_alpha and V_beta from the Clarke Transformation and then I do an atan function of (-V_alpha/V_beta). But the problem is that this development is valid only if a have a sine waveform which begins at the phase zero. This is why I thought at using zero crossing detection only for synchronisation.

Comment: I don't know enough of the Clarke transformation to say if it works or not. Does it work if the phases are not exactly 60 degrees apart? Sorry I can't help you there. But in a three phase system, basically you pick the first phase (R or L1) to be zero degrees and use that as the reference for the other voltage phases and then use those voltage phases as a reference for the corresponding current phase. That's what I can say based on a few years of designing kwh-meters for a living.